# php $_Files fails to save the file when (http) post with Qt

Tags: php, http, post, apache

I am posting a form with an image with Qt (which I do not think is important) and trying to same the image in the server but my php file keeps giving me the following error.

**Notice: Undefined index: imagename in C:\wamp\www\fileupload.php on line *5***

I used tcp monitor to detect the messages and they seem to be fine and it is as follows.

```
POST /fileupload.php HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------723690991551375881941828858
Content-Length: 467204
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Language: en-US,*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host: localhost:8089

-----------------------------723690991551375881941828858
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imagename"

1.jpg
-----------------------------723690991551375881941828858
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"

This is a Test Message
-----------------------------723690991551375881941828858
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpg
```

Then to the end image content is attached. I am using following code to save the file on the server.

```
<?php   
    $userMessage    = $_POST["message"];
    $imagefilename    = $_POST["imagename"];
    echo($userMessage.":".$imagefilename);
    if($_FILES['imagename']['error'] == 0){
         echo("Post is ready");
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagename']['error'], './1.jpg');
    }else{
         echo("ERROR");   
    }

?>
```

I am following following documentations but I can not get this to work. I appreciate if someone can give me a hint to solve the issue. I am using PHP 5.3.18 and apache 2.22.

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

http://www.saaraan.com/2012/02/post-picture-to-facebook-user-wall-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php       $userMessage    = $_POST["message"];
echo($userMessage);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "./{$_FILES['file'] ['name']}"); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've not completed your multipart request. Add this:

-----------------------------723690991551375881941828858--

to end of your post.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I do have the  bound at the end of the message.But  have not included the whole message here since the image is about 456kb :).

Comment: Have you tried replacing $_FILES['imagename'] to $_FILES['file'] ?

Comment: Thank man. It worked like a charm, I had to change 'error' to tmp_name as well. Whats up with those names. I had to use them as it is.

Comment: You just defined that, here: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.jpg"  anything you put in name, should be called in $_FILES in php

Comment: you can close the question. :)